# Optics for long haul fiber

Tags: design, fiber

Does anyone make a single fiber cwdm 10g sfp or xfp that will do 10g over a single fiber using a single 1510nm wavelength?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

Single fiber **and** single wavelength are **fundamentally incompatible.** You either need two fibers (send at each end connected to receive at the other end) and one wavelength is fine, or you need two different wavelengths so that data can travel both ways over the same fiber without conflict.

10Gb does not include a half-duplex option, which would be the only other way to get one fiber and one wavelength (and half the speed, or less than half the speed.)

"CWDM" means **C**oarse **W**avelength **D**ivision **M**ultiplexing" and is another way of saying "not one wavelength" and the "coarse" part also says "wavelengths that are not terribly close to each other" such as 1490/1510, 1310/1490, etc...

Dense WDM (DWDM) implies wavelengths that are much closer to each other.

Comment: Photons do not interact with each other, so you *can* fire a 1510nm laser in each direction without issue. No one makes a single wavelength module because it's *hard* (read: expensive) to isolate each direction without introducing loss and/or reflection.

Comment: 1490 and 1510 are 2 different windows on the mux, someone told me there was stuff that could go thru just the 1510 window bidirectional on one fiber. So far I've seen no such animal. I have done single fiber stuff with 2fiber sfps on different channels on each end of the link going into 2 different ports on the mux/demux or using add/drop filters

Answer (score 2):

They're called BiDi optical transceivers.  [I see some](http://connect.physicsworld.com/sfp-plus-10gsrlrmlrerzrcwdmdwdmbidi-transceivers/2003609.article) 1270nm / 1330nm Bi-Directional 40km Single Mode but I don't see any 1510nm.

#### [Cisco SFP-10G-BX40D-I and SFP-10G-BX40U-I (for 40Km Single-Fiber Bidirectional Applications)](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/transceiver-modules/data_sheet_c78-455693.html)

[image]

The Cisco SFP-10G-BX40D-I and SFP-10G-BX40U-I SFPs operate on a single strand of standard SMF.

A SFP-10G-BX40D-I device is always connected to a SFP-10G-BX40U-I device with a single strand of standard SMF with an operating transmission range up to 40 km.

The communication over a single strand of fiber is achieved by separating the transmission wavelength of the two devices. SFP-10G-BX40D-I transmits a 1330-nm channel and receives a 1270-nm signal. The SFP-10G-BX40U-I transmits at a 1270-nm wavelength and receives a 1330-nm signal.

The SFP-10G-BX40D-I and SFP-10G-BX40U-I SFPs support digital optical monitoring (DOM) functions according to the industry-standard SFF-8472 multisource agreement (MSA). This feature gives the end user the ability to monitor real-time parameters of the SFP, such as optical output power, optical input power, temperature, laser bias current, and transceiver supply voltage.

Comment: This is 2 different wavelengths. I was inquiring about DWDM long haul 10Gb/s using 15010 wavelength. was told such a thing existed by someone who didn't know

Comment: see http://connect.physicsworld.com/sfp-plus-10gsrlrmlrerzrcwdmdwdmbidi-transceivers/2003609.article

Answer (score 1):

As Ecnerwal states, you can't transmit signal with the same wavelength in both directions.

I'm pretty sure you know how one-eyed SFPs work, but here (http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/transceiver-modules/data_sheet_c78-455693.pdf) you can find a diagram explaining it on page 3.

If you are planing yo use single fiber SFPs/XFPs, your CWDM muxes should support them. ( like this one http://www.pandacomdirekt.com/en/products/wdm/passive-multiplexer/cwdm-multiplexer/48-channel-single-fiber.html)

Comment: Actually, you *can*. And cisco's lying about how it's done; those things use "simple" glass prisms. A true WDM splitter is an expensive, precision mirror.

Comment: this was to be used on a leased fiber, had to use their mux, 1510 wavelength leased 20 nm spacing on fiber, just not workable. There were other issues to boot

Answer (score 1):

Single Fiber, Single Wavelength,CWDM Transceivers have been commercially available for years, some with built-in Micro-OTDR Fast Fiber Fault Finder technology, but so far only for 1 Gbps to 3 Gbps applications.

Comment: yes but I was inquiring about single wavelength DWDM @ 10G. I was told such a thing existed but I was pretty sure they were blowing smoke up my ass